# AngularJS convert $http to $resource

Tags: angularjs

I am new to angular so this is probably a simple question.
I have a service that looks like this:

```
.factory('MoltinApi', ['$resource', '$http', 'moltin_options', 'moltin_auth', function ($resource, $http, options, authData) {
    var api = $resource(options.url + options.version + '/:path', {
        path: '@path'
    });

    var authenticate = function () {
        if (!options.publicKey)
            return;

        var request = {
            method: 'POST',
            url: options.url + 'oauth/access_token',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
            },
            data: "grant_type=implicit&client_id=" + options.publicKey
        };

        $http(request).success(function (response) {
            authData = response;

            console.log(response);
        });
    };

    authenticate();

    return api;
}])
```

as you can see, there is an **authenticate** method which is called when the class is instantiated. What I would like to do, is convert it from being an $http call and use $resource instead (because I am returning a $resource and it just seems messy to be using both $http and $resource).

Does anyone know how I can do that?

Comment: Are you authenticating via a RESTful service at: options.url + 'oauth/access_token'?

Comment: `$resource` is just a wrapper around `$http`, there is no reason they can't be used interchangeably.  you could use an interceptor if you want to better encapsulate your logic... I would maybe start http://www.webdeveasy.com/interceptors-in-angularjs-and-useful-examples/, there are a few snippets there that do the kind of thing you are trying here.

Comment: I can't see any examples that do the same thing. I tried creating a new service which just retuned the authenticate function and then in my interceptor, if authData.access_token was not set I would authenticate but that just created a circular dependency.